# Filter an array to return the deep level object

Tags: javascript

I have a deep level array like below,

```json
const cat = [
  {
    name: "cat 1",
    id: 1,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 1",
        id: 10,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 20 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 21 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "cat 2",
    id: 2,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 2",
        id: 20,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 30 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 31 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have to filter with subSubCat id(31) and it should return a summary value(summary2).

Comment: Is it okay if we use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get the subSubCat list, then use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=vi) to find the subSubCat item by id.

```js
const cat = [
  {
    name: "cat 1",
    id: 1,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 1",
        id: 10,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 20 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 21 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "cat 2",
    id: 2,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 2",
        id: 20,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 30 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 31 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

var subSubCats = cat.map(item => item.subCat.map(subCatItem => subCatItem.subSubCat)).flat(2);
var result = subSubCats.find(e => e.id == 31);
console.log(result.summary);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that requires a two level loop and [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const cat = [
  {
    name: "cat 1",
    id: 1,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 1",
        id: 10,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 20 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 21 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "cat 2",
    id: 2,
    subCat: [
      {
        name: "sub 2",
        id: 20,
        subSubCat: [
          { summary: "summary1", id: 30 },
          { summary: "summary2", id: 31 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];


for(let i =0 ; i < cat.length;i++){
  if(Array.isArray(cat[i].subCat)){
  let subCatArray = cat[i].subCat;
  //console.log(subCatArray);
for(let j =0 ; j < subCatArray.length;j++){
  let subSubArray = subCatArray[j].subSubCat;
  if(Array.isArray(subSubArray)){
  //console.log(subSubArray);
  let foundObject = subSubArray.find((x) => 
   x.id === 31
  );
  //console.log(foundObject);
  if(foundObject!==undefined) 
   {
    console.log(foundObject.summary);
    break;
   }
   }
  }
}
}
```